# Invertible ideals and locally free module

Tags: commutative-algebra, modules, projective-module

I was reading Pete Clark beautiful notes and in particular the invertible ideals part. I'm really stuck at the point where he demonstrates that for every locally free module $M$ there is an ivertible ideals s.t $M \cong I$. In that part, he says $M \otimes K \cong K$ (where $K$ is the field of quotient). I'm not getting this:locally this is true,but the isomorphisms change ,so what is he really saying?

Comment: in which part of the notes is this? Here are the notes for anyone interested: http://math.uga.edu/~pete/integral.pdf

Comment: Proposition 19.15 page 282

Comment: Consider some $f\in R$ such that $M_f\cong R_f$. Then, $$
M\otimes_R K\cong M\otimes_R(R_f\otimes_{R_f} K)\cong (M\otimes_R R_f)\otimes_{R_f} K\cong M_f\otimes_{R_f} K\cong R_f\otimes_{R_f}K\cong K.
$$

Comment: Ooooh i see it now. Thank u a lot!